# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have bound `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` within the constructor function but I'm still getting cannot read property undefined.

How to solve this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

class TimerConfig extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handChange(ev) {
    const newBaseTime = this.props.baseTime;

    if (ev.target.id === "hours")
      newBaseTime
        .subtract(newBaseTime.get("hour"), "hours")
        .add(parseInt(ev.target.value, 10), "hours");
    if (ev.target.id === "minutes")
      newBaseTime
        .subtract(newBaseTime.get("minutes"), "minutes")
        .add(parseInt(ev.target.value, 10), "minutes");
    if (ev.target.id === "seconds")
      newBaseTime
        .subtract(newBaseTime.get("seconds"), "seconds")
        .add(parseInt(ev.target.value, 10), "seconds");

    this.props.setBaseTime(newBaseTime);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for="hours">Hour</label>
        <input
          id="hours"
          type="number"
          defaultValue={this.props.baseTime.get("hours")}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

        <label for="minutes">min</label>
        <input
          id="minutes"
          type="number"
          defaultValue={this.props.baseTime.get("minutes")}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

        <label for="seconds">sec</label>
        <input
          id="seconds"
          type="number"
          defaultValue={this.props.baseTime.get("seconds")}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TimerConfig;
```

Comment: Jimenemex lol. I'm sorry.

Comment: Your method is misspelled, `handChange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled your method "handChange" instead of "handleChange" :)

Answer (score -2):

when you want `bind` in `constructor`, you need use `super` with `props`

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

otherwise, you can bind with following syntax:

```
handChange=(ev)=>{
//..
}
```

Comment: You only need to pass the props to `super` if you want to use `this.props` in the constructor. That is not the issue OP is having.